# Create Equation from Table of Values

Tags: algorithms

I created a table of values that return time t in seconds, given an ambient temperature. If one were to plot these values, it might look similar to a quadratic or log. I could just use the look up table, and if the value I need is between 2 points, I could interpolate.

Using this table of data points, what is the process to create an equation that would return a similar result?

Comment: There is no one algorithm that is good for all applications. For example, what are you going to do with outliers -- pay extra attention to them, throw them out, or use an algorithm that is robust against them? What data model are you going to use? There is no magic recipe.

Comment: Wow.Already figured it out. Thanks to all the mathematicians that couldn't give me some table scraps, and thanks anyhow for even reading my question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [Curve Fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting),

This describes the field of science that takes data points and creates a mathematical function that aligns well with the data points.

From the wikipedia article:

> Curve fitting can involve either interpolation, where an exact fit to the data is required, or [smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing), in which a "smooth" function is constructed that approximately fits the data.

The former (exact fit) could be programmed just like you described: given a stored version of the table, look up the values in the table and when in between two points, interpolate.

The latter (creating a smoothing approximation) requires application of one of the numerous [smoothing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing#Smoothing_algorithms) to determine the function that approximates the data points.

Comment: Thanks, already found that. I am hoping to find something very specific, not a general answer. For example, I have a few of the the x,y points. What to do next? A specific, step by step description would be useful.

Comment: @user10326, ok, you should clarify your question, then: make it more specific.  For example, are you looking for an approach to choosing a smoothing algorithm or to applying some smoothing algorithm?

Comment: @user10326, also, like smoothing, [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) has a number of algorithms to choose from, so you might ask about that.

Comment: @user10326,   Or you might ask for advice as to how to choose broadly between exact fit and smoothing?  FWIW, I'm not sure there is a "process" for this, but someone might have some advice.  In part, I would expect it has to do with the number of data points you have available (and the accuracy you're looking for), in that the more data points you have might suggest exact fit is better.  Also if you know any extra information in each circumstance, like are certain what kind of curve to use.